# using express and sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-sqlite3

so I have a database called user.db and the table are
user_id, username, hashpassword.

when I call this function from the main thread it works find

```
function check_login(username, hashpassword){
 user_db.all("SELECT * FROM users", [], (err, rows)=>{
     console.log(rows)
 });}
```

but when im calling it from the express funcation

```
app.post("/log_in/:cookie", (req, res) =>{
let cookie = req.params.cookie;
if (cookie != "")
{
    let user_id = check_login(req.body.username, req.body.hashpassword);
    console.log(user_id);
    if( user_id != ""){
        let code = create_code(get_info_by_cookie(cookie, user_id));
        res.json({"code":code})
    }
    else{
        res.json({"error":"username or password doesn't match"})
    }

}
else{
    res.json({"error":"no cookie was given"})
}
    });
```

it's printing undefined

can someone please tell me why when I call the function from another script or in the main thread it works fine but when it from the app.post() it doesn't work

Comment: Your `check_login` function isn't returning anything. This isn't a quick fix however since `user_db.all()` starts an asynchronous request and therefore needs a callback function to do something with the result. Try this: https://pastebin.com/5caxcPPJ

Comment: @ChrisG ya thanks for the help. I simplify the check_log in function to make sure people get my question. is there any way we can communicate more easily (discord ect) cause I really need the help

Comment: Try using this instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3-promise that way you don't have to wrap everything in Promise code yourself. Beyond that you need to figure it out yourself I'm afraid.

Comment: @ChrisG ok thanks, last question if i would like to add a condition in the check_login
that check if the username and password that was giving to me by parame match any of the username and password in the database and if so return the user_id of that user

Comment: You need to insert the variables into the query: `user_db.all("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND hashpassword = ?", [username, hashpassword], (err, rows) => {`

Answer (score 0):

SQLite3 functions are asynchronous, so your code can't assume it gets a return value. But more important than that, you forgot to work with Express's concept of middleware functions. Let's fix that. First, let's define our user check function as a middleware function, using normal JS conventions for naming things, not Python conventions.

First, checking for a cookie value:

```js
function checkCookie(req, res, next) {
  let cookie = req.params.cookie;
  if (!cookie)  return next(new Error("no cookie found"));
  next();
}
```

Then, checking the user's login:

```js
function checkLogin(req, res, next) {
  let username = req.body.username,
      hashpassword = req.body.hashpassword;

  user_db.all("SELECT * FROM users", [], (err, rows) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    // ...
    // You code goes here. You didn't show any, so I'm not inventing any either.
    // ...
    if (hasAccess) return next();
    return next(new Error(`user ${username} does not have access`);
  });
}
```

And now we can use this in a proper express chain:

```js
app.post("/log_in/:cookie", checkCookie, checkLogin, (req, res) => {
    // We KNOW this user has a cookie set, and the their login is good.
    // So all this function has to do is form whatever response you need
    // given that those two things are true
});
```